# Python join a list of strings

Tags: python

This seems easy, but I'm getting an error and I don't know how to get rid of it:

```
counter = 0
list1 = [''] * 11
list1[1] = '000'
list1[6] = counter
list1[10] = '999'
print(list1)
a = "^".join(list1)
print(a)
```

The error I get is

```
    a = "^".join(list1)
TypeError: sequence item 6: expected str instance, int found
```

I initialized the list of strings to null. I need the counter to assign it a unique number in each iteration.
How can I fix this error?

Comment: `list1[6] = counter` - Why are you putting an int in your list?

Comment: `a = "^".join(map(str,list1))` should be used.

Comment: The error message tells you *exactly* what the problem is, so what's still confusing you?

Comment: I had initialized the string list to empty string. So I made the mistake of assuming that the integer would be converted to a string in Python.

Comment: Why would it? You told Python to replace the empty string with a number, so it did.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to do the conversion of integer values to string, before using .join(...).

```
list1[6] = str(counter)
```

Answer (score 5):

It looks like some of the elements in the list are not strings.

You could try

```
a = "^".join(map(str, list1))
```